# How to enable C++14 with CLang in Snapcraft?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, snapcraft, snap

So I have some myapp, which needs clang of version 14 or higher for building, and following important part of snapcraft.yaml:

```
base: core20
confinement: devmode

parts:
    myapp:
        plugin: make
        source-type: local
        source: ./myapp/
        build-packages:
            - clang
            - git
            - python
            - make
            - cmake
            - ninja-build
        override-build: |
            export CC=clang-14
            export CXX=clang++-14
            mkdir build
            cd build
            cmake ..
            ninja
```

But when I try to run it with

```
sudo snapcraft --use-lxd
```

it returns:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:49 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  clang-14.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

Locally everything works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
sudo bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"
```

before exports with appropriate build-packages(lab-release, wget, software-properties-common) solved the problem.